# Code snippet breaks Markdown parser

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, editor, markdown-rendering

When editing a post, the Markdown parser **in the Preview** seems to break down after a code snippet. Everything (except the pre-formatted text) following the code snippet in **Example A** below appears incorrectly as unformatted text.

However, a `<pre>` element with at least one linebreak seems to set it straight again. In **Example B** below, the code snippet is directly followed by the pre-formatted text which makes everything work as expected.

See screenshot at the bottom of the post.

---

## Example A

```html
<p>This is a code snippet.
```

```
int main (void)
{
  return !"This is a code block.";
}
```

- This
- is
- a
- list.

```
This is pre-formatted text.
```

---

## Example B

```html
<p>This is a code snippet.
```

```
This is pre-formatted text.
```

```
int main (void)
{
  return !"This is a code block.";
}
```

- This
- is
- a
- list.

---

## Screenshot of the Preview rendering

> [image: Preview rendering]

<sup>(Click for full image)</sup>